transforming a polynomial function
I was exploring transforming polynomials (sorry if this is the wrong term).  Essentially, I found a way to rewrite polynomials in different equivalent forms analogous to changing a quadratic from standard form to its transformation form (hence transforming polynomials).  I uncovered a method that will allow me to change any polynomial of any degree into a transformed polynomial using Pascal's triangle. I want to read more on this now that I derived the technique but I lack the technical language to know what to look up.  I hope by explaining my process below, that someone could tell me what this technique is called so that I can read more about the nuances associated with it and hopefully learn of possible applications.
The technique:
Suppose we have a 5th degree polynomial $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+fx+g$ we can see that this polynomial is centered at zero in that writing it as $a(x-0)^5+b(x-0)^4+c(x-0)^3+d(x-0)^2+f(x-0)+g$ doesn't change the coefficients but what if I needed to transform the function to be centered at x=-3.  Determining the coefficients would seem daunting but I uncovered a method that makes that process pretty straightforward.
First write out pascal's triangle for the 5th degree coefficients:

now negate ever other entry for each row always starting with a positive:

now since we are centering at x=-3 aka rewriting it to be (x+3) for each variable term we would multiply diagonally (up and to the right) by increasingly higher powers of 3.

To determine each new coefficient, I need only read the diagonal in the other direction and multiple each value in that diagonal by its row coefficient (the values from the standard form) and the appropriate power of 3 (sense we are 'centering at 3').

So in this case the transformation equation becomes:



Rewriting a polynomial in terms of $x+3$ instead of $x$ is "centering at $-3$", not at $3$. To do $x-3$ instead, you would just drop the sign change step from your procedure. Then to do $x+3$, you write it as $x - (-3)$, and write out the powers of $-3$ instead (i.e., the powers of $3$ with every odd power negated). Follow the rest of the pattern, and you would get the same result. Your sign change step is just applying the negations early,

That said, I don't really see how this is easier to accomplish than just using Pascal's triangle to expand each of the $(x+3)^k$, multiply it through by the $k$-th coefficient, then add up the coefficients of like terms.

Thank you for replying. How would you recenter $4x^3+3x-18$ using your method above if I wanted to recenter it at x=2?

Replace $x$ by $x-2: 4(x-2)^3 + 3(x-2) - 18$. Now $$4(x-2)^3 = 4x^3 - 4\cdot3\cdot2 x^2 + 4\cdot3\cdot 2^2x - 4\cdot2^3 = 4x^3 - 24x^2+48x-32\3(x-2) - 18 = 3x -24$$ Adding the like powers gives $$4x^3 - 24x^2 + 51x - 56$$

We are talking about two different things.  The point of of my post was to create an identical polynomial but rewriting it such that  instead of the constant term being the value found at (0, k1) it now be (2,k2) (2 in this case since we centered at x=2.

So in this case: $4x^3 +3x-18$ is equivalent to $4(x-2)^3+24(x-2)+51(x-2)+20$

Found by: $4(1)(x-2)^3+(234-01)x^2+(434+3-20+31)x+84-40+23-18$

I don't mean transform in the sense that I want to shift the graph but rather I am able to rewrite any polynomial keeping the graph the same but changing the meaning of constant term. Instead of the constant being (0,k). I can rewrite it using the above technique to make it any (n, k1) that I desire.

We are talking about exactly the same thing. You are just running it in the opposite direction. Did you not notice that your coefficients and mine are the same, except for sign, and the constant term? The sign difference comes from the reversal of direction, and the constant term comes because the reversed direction ends up in the oppostie point. The supposed change of polynomial is only because I was a little lazy in my notation and did not change the letter used to represent the translated variable.

You might want to study this transform in the context of solving a cubic equation. If you start with $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$. Divide by $a$ on both sides. Then the coefficient of the $x^3$ term is 1. Then substitute $x=u+q$. You now have a polynomial in $u$ .For the right value of $q$, you can force the coefficient of $u^2$ to be 0. So you've taken a polynomial in 4 coefficients and reduced it to a polynomial in 2 variable coefficients and 1 fixed coefficient. From there, you can apply a number of procedures to solve the reduced polynomial.

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I need more room than the comments provide to explain what I was referring to:
You have a polynomial $P(x)$, and your purpose is to rewrite it as $Q(x - r)$ for some constant $r$, where $Q$ is another polynomial. So $P(x) = Q(x-r)$. In particular, the constant term of $Q$ is $Q(0) = P(r)$, as you've discussed. Your object is to determine the polynomial $Q$.
The way I would do this is to let $t = x - r$, so $x = t + r$, and $$Q(t) = P(t + r)$$Next, you expand the various powers of $t + r$ that arise in $P(t+r)$ using Pascal's Triangle, multiply them by the appropriate coefficients of $P$, then add up the like terms in $t$ to get $Q(t)$. Let me use a somewhat more complicated polynomial than your example to illustrate the process:
$P(x) = x^4 - 3x^3 + 2x^2 - 3x - 1$, and $r = 2$. Then by Pascal's Triangle:
$$\begin{align}&(t + 2)^0 = 1\\
&(t + 2)^1 = t + 2\\
&(t + 2)^2 = t^2 + 2\cdot 2t + 2^2\\
&(t + 2)^3 = t^3 + 3\cdot 2t^2 + 3\cdot 2^2t + 2^3\\
&(t + 2)^4 = t^4 + 4\cdot 2t^3 + 6\cdot 2^2t^2 + 4\cdot 2^3t +2^4
\end{align}$$
and $Q(t) = P(t+2)$ is
$$\begin{align}
t^4 + 8t^3 + 24t^2 + 32t &+16\\
-3t^3 -18t^2 -36t &- 24\\
+2t^2 + 8t &+ 8\\
-3t &- 6\\
&-1\\\hline
t^4+5t^3+8t^2+t&-7
\end{align}$$
So $$P(x) = Q(x - 2) = (x-2)^4 + 5(x-2)^3 + 8(x-2)^2 + (x-2) - 7$$
I do not claim that this method is any easier to calculate than yours, but I also do not see that it is particularly harder to calculate than yours. And it does have an advantage over yours in that it doesn't have to be memorized by itself. All one needs to do is understand how $Q$ and $P$ are related - which is part of the set-up of the problem, so it is something one needs to understand anyway, and the rest is just standard polynomial handling that should already be known. It doesn't require learning a special algorithm for a process that one doesn't have to do all that often.
That is not to say that your process doesn't have value. Algorithms and calculation methods are a subject of study in their own right, not just for their utility. And if someone did have to do such expansions repeatedly, your algorithm could be more convenient for organizing the work.

Thank you for clarifying. I understand now.
